# How to create a curve function

Tags: r, curve-fitting, lme4, glmm

I am getting acquainted with statistics and R and got stuck creating a curve() to fit my model. I am hoping someone could give me some insight on how to overcome that.
This is my model:

```
Complete_Data_glmer2<-glmer(cbind(n_infected, Healthy) ~ 
         visit_rate_1000_per_yr * track_density + pop_density + 
         cane_toad1 + (1 | creek_id), 
         family="binomial", data =  taudactylus_rheophilus, 
         control=glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", 
                              optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))
```

I am trying to represent this information in a binary graph of presence/ absence of n_infected x the predictors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, your question isn't really clear at the moment. It sounds like you're trying to create a plot of the model predictions. `sjPlot` is one package that can help; you can also generate predictions with the `ggeffects`, `marginaleffects`, or `emmeans` packages and add them to a plot (`ggplot`-based or base-R)